# I can't delete from my SQL database using JTable

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, jtable

So... I want to delete a row from by database using a JTable, but I don't know why it doesn't get deleted, maybe the sintaxis of the DELETE isntruction is wrong...

```
borrar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e)
        {

             System.out.println(tabla_proveedor.getSelectedRow());

            if (tabla_proveedor.getSelectedRow()!=-1){

                id_borrado=datos_proveedor[tabla_proveedor.getSelectedRow()][0];
                System.out.println(id_borrado);

            try{
            Statement st = conexion.createStatement();
            st.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM `boticaebenezer`.`proveedores` WHERE `proveedores`.`id_proveedor` = id_borrado;'");
            System.out.println("Se borró");


            }
            catch (SQLException s){
                System.out.println("SQLException: " + s.getMessage());
                System.out.println(s.getErrorCode());

            }

        }
        }


});
```

Updated my program like this, and this is the Error I get from the catch.

SQLException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''' at line 1

1064

I don't know how to evaluate if id_proveedor has the same value as the String id_borrado

Edit: found the solution, the real sitnaxis was:
    st.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM `boticaebenezer`.`proveedores` WHERE `proveedores`.`id_proveedor` = '" + id_borrado + "';");

Thanks to all your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `executeUpdate` for database write operations. Also Use `PreparedStatement` instead to protect against [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

```
String sql = "DELETE FROM proveedores WHERE id_proveedor=?";
PreparedStatement preparedStatement =  conexion.prepareStatement(sql);
preparedStatement.setString(1, "id_borrado");

int rows = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Finally, always display exception messages in Exception blocks to help source the problem of the `SQLException`.

Comment: Mmm, now it is displaying
    System.out.println("Se borró");
Properly, but still won't delete the row, could you please check the sintaxis?

Comment: I would think remove the quotes around `id_proveedor` if that is the name of your column.

Comment: I edited the question, with updated code to see if it helps more, I tried the quotes and nothing.

Comment: I used DELETE FROM proveedores WHERE id_proveedor='Test'
It deleted the row that had the id "Test", but in my java program, I want it to delete the row that has the same value as the String "id_borrado"

I don't know the sintaxis for the String evaluation, that's my question.

Comment: @Adrian Use a `PreparedStatement` with a `?` placeholder. Google it.

Comment: Already found the answer, edited the question with the solution heh, thanks :D

Comment: @Adrian `String` concatenation leaves the SQL code vulnerable to attack. See the `PreparedStatement` in the update

Comment: It's for a school project, I just need it to work, that's all